# Why the terminal says I still running a job on this ssh?

Tags: ssh

I am doing a project where I need to use my school's gpu servers. When I try to connect to a server the system says I am running another job on another server called 'ugcpu4'.

I login to 'ugcpu4', use command `kill -9 -1` to kill all activity and logout. When I try to connect to another server, it still say there is a job on 'ugcpu4'. [[image: ssh_error]]

How can I fix this and let me enter another ssh.

Comment: This seems to be a specific implementation done by your university. I recommend contacting your system administration department.

Comment: With "kill -9 -1" you're killing all processes your user can kill. It's possible you scheduled a job that's running under different credentials so you would need to use the correct cluster commands to identify that process and kill it.